# Is it posible to insert into the bigQuery table rows with different fields?

Tags: google-bigquery

Using bigQuery UI I've created new table `free_schem_table` and haven't set any schema, then I tried to execute:

```
insert into my_dataset.free_schema_table (chatSessionId, chatRequestId,senderType,senderFriendlyName)
values ("123", "1234", "CUSTOMER", "Player")
```

But BigQuery UI demonsrtrated me the popup where written:

```
Column chatSessionId is not present in table my_dataset.free_schema_table at [1:43]
```

I expected that BiqQuery is a NoSql storage and I should be able to insert rows with different columns.

How could I achieve it ?

### P.S.

schema:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery requires a schema with strong type.

If you need free schema, similar thing in BigQuery is to define a single column in STRING type and store JSON inside.

[JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) will help you extract field from JSON string later, but you don't benefit from BigQuery's optimization if you predefine your schema and save data in different columns.

Comment: O am really confused. But what about BigTable ? is it required  schema  either ?

Comment: I never used BigTable, but in concept it is more like what you're looking for.